# UIview.hidden doesn't disappear but hides behind another view

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

So I am trying to hide a UIView but something weird is happening. After using this line of code:

```
ntcCircleView.hidden = YES;
```

The view won't disappear, but it hides behind another UIView.

This is the complete code I use:

```
UIView* NtcContainer=[[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(self.view.frame.size.width - 40-17, 3, 40, 40)];
UIView* NtcView=[[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5, 0, 40, 40)];


notificationButton  = [ZFRippleButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
notificationButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 40, 40);
notificationButton.layer.cornerRadius=menuButton.frame.size.width/2;
[notificationButton addTarget:self action:@selector(goToNotificationsList:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
notificationImage=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 12, 20, 20)];
notificationImage.image=[UIImage imageNamed:[HotelStay sharedInstance].icon.Notification];

ntcCircleView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20,5,16,16)];
ntcCircleView.alpha = 0.7;
ntcCircleView.layer.cornerRadius = ntcCircleView.frame.size.width/2;  // half the width/height
ntcCircleView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];

ntcNumberLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,16,16)];
ntcNumberLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
[ntcNumberLabel setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
[ntcNumberLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue" size:11.0]];

[ntcCircleView addSubview:ntcNumberLabel]; 
int ntcNum = [dataManager getUnreadNotificationNumber];
if (ntcNum==0)
{
    ntcCircleView.hidden = YES;
}else
{
    ntcNumberLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",ntcNum];
}

[NtcView addSubview:notificationImage];
[NtcView addSubview:notificationButton];
[NtcView addSubview:ntcCircleView];
[NtcContainer addSubview:NtcView];

[self.view addSubview:NtcContainer];
```

So *ntcCircleView* after hidding it, just goes behind *notificationImage*.

What drives me crazy, is that I use successfully the exact same code in another Views  with the only difference the last line. Instead of using:

```
[self.view addSubview:NtcContainer];
```

I add the views to the navigation bar like this:

```
UIBarButtonItem *ntcBarItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:NtcContainer];
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = ntcBarItem;
```

What am I missing here ?

*UPDATE*

I also noticed that this bug happens only when I use

```
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

to navigate back to the view.

Comment: I think you need to check here, (ntcNum==0) ntcNum is not equal to Zero.

Comment: It is, I used breakpoint.

Comment: Is ntcNum equal to zero. Put some NSLog

Comment: first of all, why separate view for circle? just set background color of ntcNumberLabel  when required, and set its corner radius, that's better way. ntcCircleView.hidden = YES;  code is correct, just make sure you are not calling this whole code multiple time, which can craete   multiple instance of ntcCircleView -- current instance hidden but previous stay there.

Comment: It's called only once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. I was using a deprecated method (viewDidUnload) to release the notification observer.

Answer (score 1):

You need to update these snippet:

```
[NtcView addSubview:notificationImage];
[NtcView addSubview:notificationButton];
[NtcView addSubview:ntcCircleView];
[NtcContainer addSubview:NtcView];
```

to:

```
[NtcView addSubview:notificationButton];
[NtcView addSubview:ntcCircleView];
[NtcView addSubview:notificationImage];
[NtcContainer addSubview:NtcView];
```

It will solve your problem.